# Hindi to English Transliteration

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, transliteration

Is there a python library for transliterating Hindi to English?

e.g. "खाया" should be converted to "khaya"

Answer (score 15):

The less crappy transcoder I know of is [sanscript](https://github.com/sanskrit/sanskrit/blob/master/sanskrit/transliterate/sanscript.py). It is intended to transliterate Sanskrit text, but is of course also suited for Hindi, as they both use the Nagari notation. There are some issues in the code, and it does not do any validation of the input, but it has a large choice of scripts (not only Nagari).

Comment: -1? Seriously? Come on, get a life.