# I want to convert 'Name' data of customers in English Text, present/written with me in Hindi Language text

Tags: python, google-translate, hindi

I am using "from googletrans import Translator"   But it just translate names in English language .

For example I have name as :दर्पण
It got converted as : "Mirror" using googletrans .I want this to be "Darpan" only

Any suggestions please?

Comment: That's not translation. That's transliteration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hindi to English Transliteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076055/hindi-to-english-transliteration)